# String to Int in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I need to convert a String to Int in Scala. If the string is not a number I would like to return `None` rather than throw an exception.

I found the following [solution](https://coderwall.com/p/lcxjzw)

```
def toMaybeInt(s:String) = {
  import scala.util.control.Exception._
  catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]) opt s.toInt
}
```

Does it make sense ? Would you change/improve it ?

Comment: Other than using `Try` (@brian's answer), I would name the method `toIntOption` to be more in line with standard Scala names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use `scala.util.Try` which returns `Success` or `Failure` for a computation that may throw an exception.

```
scala> val zero = "0"
zero: String = 0

scala> val foo = "foo"
foo: String = foo

scala> scala.util.Try(zero.toInt)
res5: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(0)

scala> scala.util.Try(foo.toInt)
res6: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo")
```

So, `toMaybeInt(s: String)` becomes:

```
def toMaybeInt(s:String) = {
  scala.util.Try(s.toInt)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to return `Option` now.

Comment: @Michael Use `toOption`.

Comment: `Catch[+T].toOption` ?

Comment: `scala.util.Try("0".toInt).toOption` or similarly `scala.util.Try("foo".toInt).toOption` will return `Some(0)` or `None`.

Answer (score 4):

For getting an option in any case, regardless of possible exceptions due to number malformation,

```
import scala.util.Try

def toOptInt(s:String) = Try(s.toInt) toOption
```

Then

```
scala> toOptInt("123")
res2: Option[Int] = Some(123)

scala> toOptInt("1a23")
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Further, consider

```
implicit class convertToOptInt(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def toOptInt() = Try(s.toInt) toOption
}
```

Hence

```
scala> "123".toOptInt
res5: Option[Int] = Some(123)

scala> "1a23".toOptInt
res6: Option[Int] = None
```